# On LinkedBlockingQueue, clarification needed

Tags: java, queue

Consider the following snippet. `qIn` is a `BlockingQueue`, `LinkedBlockingQueue` implementation

```
    while (true) {
        try {
            // retrieved = qIn.poll(999, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);  works
            retrieved = qIn.poll();                            // fails

            if (retrieved != null)
                consume(retrieved);

            if (!Producer.isAddingData && qIn.size() == 0)
                break;

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Let me clarify what i mean by `works` and `fails`. When i say `qIn.poll()` fails, i refer to the fact that sometimes not all data in queue is processed.

Why it is the wait (`qIn.poll(999, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` necessary

```
retrieved = qIn.poll(999, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // works
retrieved = qIn.poll();                           // fails
```

When the following check is always being performed? Basically the check is **"If your producer is no longer adding data and the queue to pull from contains no data, break**"

```
if (!StopwordsFilter.isAddingData && qIn.size() == 0)
   break;
```

I wonder, under what circumstance `qIn.poll();` fails?

Defined as follows, considering we break only when there is nothing to take, why would it break?

> retrieves and removes the head of this queue, or returns null if this
>   queue is empty.

PS: I should add that `qIn.poll()` fails sometimes, not all the time

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `poll` doesn't do any waiting at all, and returns `null` if there's nothing in the queue _right now._

Comment: That's fine though, the code will look until there is something, or .. producer is not publishing and there is nothing to take

Comment: What do you mean by "fails," then?  It's not clear.

Comment: I am looking to explain why `qIn.poll(999, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` never misses data in queue and `qIn.poll()` sometimes does. Obviously considering my `break` condition.

Comment: Because the information hasn't been added to the queue _quite_ yet, that's why -- but perhaps it might be added in a couple more milliseconds.  `poll()` doesn't do any waiting at all.

Comment: Ok, then the natural question is .. how many milliseconds is appropriate to wait for in this case. How can one reliably put in a number without simply guessing?

Comment: Heh.  You don't.  You go ahead and guess.

Comment: Is it ok then to always put large number of milliseconds to wait for?, knowing that that number will never be reached? Seems like a sloppy thing to do. Also, please `answer` the question, so i can accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`poll()` can return `null` because the information hasn't been added to the queue quite yet, that's why -- but perhaps it might be added in a couple more milliseconds. poll() doesn't do any waiting *at all*.

If you want to wait...then you're going to need to guess an upper bound on the time to wait.  There's no really good way of predicting this, but you can probably be generous -- if I understand the situation correctly, you're *usually* adding things to the queue quite quickly.

Comment: Is it possible to learn how many actually milliseconds has passed till data has arrived? I wonder what the latency is here.

Comment: This is quite tricky, especially because the possibility exists (in principle) that multiple threads are adding to the queue at once -- in which case you could have two values being nearly-simultaneously added!  If you can arrange it, timing operations is generally most reliably done using Guava's [Stopwatch](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html).